# NPM install from git repository not loading any Javascript files

Tags: reactjs, git, azure, npm

I am trying to load a component from a personal git repository using NPM. It looks like it is finding the repo but it is only loading the package.json, Readme and CSS files. It is not loading any javascript code. I have checked the src file in the repo and all the code is there. I'm out of ideas.

The command I used was `npm install --save git+ssh://[MY AZURE REPO URI]`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have all your changes in the default branch of your repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have `.npmignore` file(s) in your repository. If files with JavaScript code are listed in `.npmignore`, then they will not be installed to `node_modules` when you run `npm install`.

Another way files can get excluded from the install is if your `package.json` has `files` field. From NPM docs:

> The optional files field is an array of file patterns that describes the entries to be included when your package is installed as a dependency.

The default value for `files` is `["*"]`, and if it is set to something else, then that determines which files get included in the install.